# Python 3.5.1 on CentOS 6 - getting error "undefined symbol: PyCObject_FromVoidPtr" when restarting Apache

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to run Django on a server with CentOS and Apache2. Using mod_wsgi.

I've created a project with django just to make the "It works!" to see everything is working. But when I try to run httpd I get:

```
undefined symbol: PyCObject_FromVoidPtr
```

And wsgi module fails to load.

I'm using mod_wsgi-3.2.

Has anyone gone through a similar problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have mod_wsgi 3.2 installed (which is ancient), it is going to be compiled for system Python 2.6 (or older). You can't force mod_wsgi to use a virtual environment for a different Python version. You will need to uninstall the system mod_wsgi package and compile and install mod_wsgi yourself from source code. See:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi/4.5.22